# 'Project Structure' in Android Studio doesn't launch

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having this issue launching the File>Project Structure. Everytime I try to I'm told the following:

> ```
> 3:40:36 PM NullPointerException: null
> 3:40:47 PM Throwable: module editors was not disposed
> 3:40:49 PM Throwable: module editors was not disposed (on second try)
> ```

Apparently the first issue is due to an exception in the Android Support plugin and the second and third are due to an exception in the Android Studio core. Anybody know what this means and how I can solve it?

EDIT: These are the details of the issue:

> ```
> module editors was not disposed
> java.lang.Throwable
> at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:113)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ModulesConfigurator$5.run(ModulesConfigurator.java:196)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1002)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ModulesConfigurator.resetModuleEditors(ModulesConfigurator.java:192)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.StructureConfigurableContext.reset(StructureConfigurableContext.java:176)
> at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ProjectStructureConfigurable.reset(ProjectStructureConfigurable.java:336)
> at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:66)
> at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:89)
> at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:104)
> at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:242)
> at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:217)
> at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:40)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:162)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:260)
> at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:892)
> at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:114)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:230)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:104)
> at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:512)
> at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:44)
> at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:532)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:696)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.Try the following

close Android studio.Open CMD

Try adb `kill-server` and adb `start-server` and restart the adb and then studio.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Unselect the option.I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue & Exception, but only in my main project, which had a mixture of Java, Android, Groovy and Robolectric modules in them. I think trying to get Robolectric to work in AS led to the problem you describe, but I'm not 100% sure.

Long story short: After hours of editing IML files and config files in the .idea folder, I gave up; created a fresh Project, then for each module in the original project, I
  i) Manually recreated an empty module in the new project of the required type (Java/ Android etc.)
  ii) Copied the source code (and gradle files) to the new project. I did NOT copy any .iml or .idea configuration files.

Not a great solution, but I got the Project Structure dialog back. And everything seems to be playing nice now.